# Pinning Stateful Tasks in Stateless microservice cluster

Tags: microservices, distributed-computing

We have a microservice whose multiple instances are running for High Availablity and Scaling. But although we have multipe stateless microservice there are some tasks which needs to be singleton.

For example, let's say we have to fetch emails from multiple email Ids and do some work on those emails. Now since I would like to ensure same emails are not processed multiple times I would want only one microservice instance to make connection to a specific email profile.

Now let's say I have 2 Microservice instances `InsA` and `InsB` and I have 4 email profiles E1, E2, E3 and E4. Now assuming there are almost equal rate of messages in each email profile, my ideal scenario would be that each microservice makes a connection to 2 email profiles. (InsA to E1 And E2, InsB to E3 and E4). Also, if `InsA` goes down I would like to temporarily move `E1` and `E2` to `InsB` until `InsA` is active again. If we scale up, the email profiles must be redistributed.

1. Are there some known patterns to solve this problem?
2. Are we on the right direction atleast or is there something we are missing here? Is distributing the email connection among stateless microservices a good idea or there are also some other ways to solve this problem?

---

Media profile is just one of the cases where we have this problem. I agree that in case of email fetching we can have a separate process responsible for fetching emails periodically and the email tasks can then be queued and processed separately. But we have other scenarios as well where this solution is not possible. I will mention couple of other cases where making the application completely stateless is not possible.

CASE 1 - We need to create a persistent socket connection with asterisk (Third party service). Why persistent connection? Because this is the only way asterisk provides integration for events. Now as we see here we can connect to multiple asterisk instances and even if we create a separate process to handle events, a single process won't be able to connect with all asterisks for scaling reasons (too many events from one asterisk - not like email fetching). So we have to again distribute the asterisk connection among more processes. Again same problem here.

CASE 2 - We need to process some events in near real time from a queue and ordering of events from a specific context is very important here. Now one of the solution to preserver ordering and scaling across nodes simultaneously would be sharding of a queue based on contextId of event. So far So Good. But here comes the problem. To maintain ordering of events we need to ensure that only one consumer for a particular shard is running at any point of time. Now if the node goes down the consumer needs to be initialized to another node. (FYI - We are using rabbitMQ not Kafka because persisting the events will cause more delay which is not acceptable and for sharding in rabbitMQ, we need to implement this using multiple rabbitMQ queues. You can read more about sharding events in rabbitMQ online).

Comment: Possibly worth looking at something like https://flink.apache.org/ ?

Comment: Also, a load balancer of some sort would seem to be applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

You're pinning tasks/connections to specific instances of your microservices, which is an anti-pattern in this context. Such pinning means that your instances have implicit state, which makes it difficult to scale up or down. They are no longer stateless. In some cases (e.g. maintaining open network connections for push notifications) it's truly necessary to keep the connection on a specific machine. Otherwise, it's typically much better to manage pending tasks externally, e.g. with a job queue that each service instance fetches new jobs from.

In this particular scenario, it may also be possible to separate “fetching emails” from “processing emails”. Fetching emails could indeed require long-lived open connections, e.g. when IMAP push is involved. If further processing of these emails is required, it may be beneficial to stuff them into a message queue and let a different service do this processing asynchronously. If you don't require long-lived connections but instead regularly poll for new emails, it may be better to store information about upcoming polling events in a database or message queue, from which each service gets its next task. The difficult part is doing this in a way that is fault-tolerant, e.g. if a server takes a task but does not complete it. How to solve this depends on what kind of work is being done with these emails, and whether any order of events has to be maintained. In many cases, it's possible to ensure that each task is completed successfully at least once or at most once, but exactly-once completion is usually impossible if failure can occur.

Comment: Thanks Amon :). I agree that having a separate process for managing media profiles is a better solution. But media process is just one such case. We have some other cases as well where having a separate process would lead to same problem. I have edited my question to provide better understanding of another scenario where this is not possible. :)